# Vim: Aligning columns by whitespace

Tags: regex, vim, formatting

what for a regex is needed for formating some lines from

```
0 0 0      
00 00 00  
000 000 00
0 00 000 
000 00 0   
000 0 000
```

to

```
  0   0   0
 00  00  00
000 000 000
  0  00 000
000  00   0
000   0 000
```

?

TIA

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For such tasks, I'd take a look at ["DrChips Alignment Tool for Vim"](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/align.html)

Answer (score 11):

[Watch this](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/aligning-text-with-tabular-vim/):

> There are times when you can improve the readability of your code by lining up the elements on neighbouring lines. In this episode, I demonstrate how this can be achieved using the [Tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) plugin...